# HAL, JSONAPI, Collection+json, odata other hypermedia pro and cons

Tags: rest, odata, json-api, hypermedia

There is so many hypermedia available fora restful api. I am not sure which one is suitable for which case. It is my first attempt for restful api so I cant foresee problem and advantage of using it. What I want is which can be queried and also with batch support (specially for GET request).

Odata seems feature complete and also oasis standard but it seems overkill for me. Its query capability is flexible yet complex. more over it there is not any php implementation of odata 4. If I go with it I need to do it on my own. Which I am trying to avoid now.

Hal Seems too simple to do anything much.

Collection+json looks good. But As it seems does not have any batch operation capability

jsonapi: It looks simple. has both query capability and batch operation (with extension). but it does not support batch operation of GET request. it is also in stable status. But I cant find any review of it yet.

What is your experience regarding this? how should i choose a hypermedia among them? Any insight will be helpfull. I would also like to hear any other hypermedia except this.

Currently I am confused between json-api and collection+json.

Answer (score -1):

> Hal Seems too simple to do anything much.

It's used as the basis for many different production APIs by some of the biggest companies in the world eg. Amazon

Comment: Sorry, but it does not answer my question. I dont understand why one is better than other and how to choose it so it fix any particular needs.

Comment: What is your final decision?:) I have the same issue.